# Remove all .axd files from a webpage in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: .net, ajax, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

I have added Ajax ToolKit in my website, but due to heavy load on the page we want to remove the Ajax Tool Kit.

To remove I deleted the file from the bin folder, Removed the control tab from Tools.

Now when I run the website, I see certain Webresource.axd? and Scriptresource.axd? script files in the project.

One file is too heavy around 55 KBs which affects the load time of the page.

Note: I am using Script Manager and update panel on the page, but all reference to Ajax ToolKit is removed. my project is a website in .NET 2010 using 4.0 framework.

Comment: The ScriptManager adds a reference to Microsoft Ajax that is required for UpdatePanel.

Comment: ya that's fine but do i need more than one file, i got 4 files which loads and due to which the page load time increases

Comment: Yes there are, but they're lightweight. IMO, to increase your application performance use Microsoft CDN (Set EnableCdn property to true).

Comment: How ever can please let me know the advantages n disadvantages of the property, what exactly enabling will do and what is this property for?

Comment: Check it out... http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of such unnecessary .axd files use Ajax.dll from Microsoft and wirte your own code for it. example for using Ajax is as follows.

Suppose i am using Multiple Delete function on button click and i dont want to use Update panel due to page load try this.

```
using Ajax;
```

Register your control  on Page Load event
page_Load

```
Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(Admin_UserControls_Delete));
```

method

```
[Ajax.AjaxMethod()]
 public int deleteRecords(int ID,string spName)
 {
   // delete code block
 }


> In your **markup source on client click of button** call the javascript.

function callbackmethod(response) {
        if (response.value > 0) {
            alert("Record deleted Successfully");
            window.location.reload();
        }
        else {
            alert("Can Not Delete Record,It is being Used");
        }
}

function DeleteMultipleRecords() {

    //delete block to get the param values 
  var str = Admin_UserControls_Delete.deleteRecords(param1,param2,callbackmethod);
}
```